# Can you get Armor proficiency with the Skilled feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, skills, armor, proficiency

I have a PC that wants to play a variant human warlock, but uses heavy armor and has the feat *Skilled* which states you gain proficiency in any combination of 3 skills or tools. Is heavy or any armor considered a skill?

Comment: Why does the skills tag apply?

Comment: @MrHiTech why wouldn't it?

Comment: @PurpleMonkey Because it’s asking about the _skilled feat_, but the question has nothing to do with skills.

Comment: @MrHiTech The question is whether they are skills, so [[tag:skills]] seems to describe a central aspect of the question. Remember that tags describe the core question rather than what the answers may be, so (e.g.) knowing that the answer is that skills aren’t involved doesn’t affect the tags on the *question*.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I was under the impression that it was asking whether armor was a _tool_, not a skill.

Comment: @MrHiTech The sentence with the question mark is “Is heavy or any armor considered a skill?”

Answer (score 32):

**No**

Armor is not a tool or a skill. In every class description it lists tool and skill proficiencies separate from armor and weapons. Additionally there are entire feats that grant armor proficiency, (Lightly Armored, Moderately Armored, Heavily Armored each of which requires proficiency in the lower type of armor) so I'd advise your warlock to take Moderately Armored and then at 4th level take Heavily Armored to get heavy armor proficiency.

Comment: the warlock would probably be better served taking a level or two in fighter. If he's gonna do stuff that requires heavy armor, they'll come in handy as well.

Comment: @PixelMaster Multiclassing into Fighter doesn't grant heavy armor proficiency, only light and medium armor. [See the relevant section of the basic rules.](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/customization-options#MulticlassingProficiencies)

Comment: @V2Blast He could start as a fighter and then take levels in Warlock for the proficiency in all armors and weapons.

Comment: He could multiclass into War Cleric